# Openlaszlo dragging issue

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I am try to drag a view to another view containing an html. But for some reason i am not able to drag over the html. Can any one tell me what is wrong in this code.

```
<canvas>
<include href="iFrame.lzx"/> 

<view y="5" width="100" height="50" bgcolor="green">
<handler name="oninit">
this.bringToFront();
</handler>
        <dragstate name="drg"/>
        <text width="100%" bgcolor="gray" onmousedown="parent.drg.apply()" onmouseup="parent.drg.remove()">Drag me</text>

    </view>

<view y="150" width="100%" height="300" bgcolor="blue" >
        <html id="htdevice" src="http://www.openlaszlo.org" x="15" y="15" width="${parent.width - 30}" height="${parent.height - 30}"/>

    </view>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

you wrote mouse event listeners on text tag put your mouse on text then you can easily drag or write mouse event listeners for view tag then you can drag the view by putting your mouse pointer any where on the view(green)